# How do I automatically take the most recently modified .txt file in a folder, convert it to .xlsx, and overwrite an existing .xlsx file?

Tags: r, excel, text, automation, file-conversion

I am attempting to use R to automate data freshness in an Excel document, but am new to coding and am having trouble.

Here's the scenario:

Each morning, I get a .txt file with a unique name (same information) deposited into the same folder. It does not overwrite the previous day's .txt file, it simply creates a new one.

I am hoping to use R to automatically read the most recent .txt file from the folder, convert it to .xlsx, and have it update/overwrite an existing .xlsx file. This .xlsx file will serve as the basis for a dashboard, so it's important that the same .xlsx file is getting the new information from each day's .txt file.

Again, I'm very new to coding, so I don't have the most educated guess as to how this would be coded, but below is my best starting attempt:

```
require(readtext)
require(dplyr)
require(eeptools)

#Set Working Directory

setwd("G:\\My Drive\\Dashboards\\Text Files")

#Read latest text file

data_files <- file.info(Sys.glob("*.txt"))
row.names(data_files)[which.max(data_files[["ctime"]])]
```

Does anybody know exactly how I would have to code this?

Thank you in advance for your help. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I would use Autoit or Python, because I'm not familiar with R. Logic: Delete the old files. Open your txt file, convert it, save it with your target name. done.

Answer (score 1):

You had a good start. If you're sure `ctime` will get the most recent file and not `mtime` (which may be more applicable if the data is being updated), you've already got much of the data reading problem done. Assuming there's no other changes to be made to the file, you can just read it in to R and then save it as an Excel file. I prefer using the `openxlsx` package for Excel files, so that's what I've used here.

```
library(openxlsx)
file_dir <- "G:\\My Drive\\Dashboards\\Text Files\\"

files <- file.info(list.files(file_dir, ".txt", full.names = T))
my_dat_file <- rownames(files)[which.max(files$mtime)]

## this step may vary depending on the actual format of your data 
mydat <- read.table(my_dat_file, header = T)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(mydat, 
                     file = paste0(file_dir, "my_file_name.xlsx"), 
                     overwrite = TRUE)
```

If you're looking to automate it and you're using Windows you should look into a package like `taskscheduleR` ([github here](https://github.com/cran/taskscheduleR)) or set up your own task so the script is run every day automatically and you don't have to do it yourself. If you're using Linux you could try `cronR`